# python "import media" didn't work but there was "media.py"

Tags: python

I read a book to learn python programming, it showed the code :

```
import media
```

So I downloaded `gwpy-code.zip` from the link http://pragprog.com/titles/gwpy/source_code and installed `PyGraphics-2.0.win32.exe` . In the path `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygraphics` there really was `media.py` ! But why `import media` didn't work ?
(ps: I also tried this `C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install nose` in the DOS box, still not work...)
Best Regards :)

Comment: do you see `__init__.py` in the `site-package\pygraphics` directory or do you see `site-package\pygraphics` in `sys.path`? The package uses  a rare distutils' `extra_path` parameter in its `setup.py` so setuptools-based tools do not support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from pygraphics import media
```

If you're not familiar with importing modules in Python yet, a brief [primer](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt) might be useful.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

If you try the code above, you will see a bunch of directories on your system path. `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` should be one of these.

To import a file located on your system path, you can use `import filename` (for filename.py). If the file lies in a subdirectory, e.g. `dir1/dir2/filename.py`, it can be imported using `import dir1.dir2.filename`.

Note: A directory acts as a 'package' if it contains a file called `__init__.py`. A file that can be imported is called a 'module'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
from pygraphics import media
```

The reason is that Python looks in the `site-packages` directory for packages. The file `media.py` is within the folder (and therefore the package) `pygraphics`, so you can't get to it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Before you import media, you must import ampy.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to say

```
from pygraphics import media
```